# Прокрутка ScrollView до конца после добавления нового элемента

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Есть `scrollView` в который постепенно добавляются `view`, нужно сделать так что  бы  при добавлении  нового `view` происходила прокрутка до самого низу. 
Для этого я использую следующий код, но прокрутка происходит ровно до предпоследнего элемента, а не последнего.

```
scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

**scroll_view.xml**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Только что такое делал у себя=)

```
private void scrollDialogDown() {
        mainScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: отлично, это работает.